# How to encapsulate display formatting in a jupyter cell?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have some code (from another stackoverflow question) that shows a dataframe and an image side by side. This works fine when executed from a Jupyter cell:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython import display
from IPython.display import HTML, Image

widget1 = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})
widget2 = widgets.Output(layout={'border': '1px solid black'})
with widget1:
    display.display(HTML(df.to_html(index=False))) #display a dataframe
with widget2:
    display.display(Image(filename='foo.png', width=1050)) #display the image.

hbox = widgets.HBox([widget1, widget2])
hbox
```

However this will be way to confusing for my audience. How can I encapsulate this code in a module that I then `import` and execute from the notebook?

Comment: wrap it in a function, put it an another file in the same directory, and import it?

Comment: That works great for complex plots and charts. But not for this side by side view. I should have put in the question that I tried this for an afternoon before asking the question on stackoverflow.